# Gamepad Support Android

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, motionevent

I am trying to add gamepad support to my game but I can't find anywhere how to get the motion events from a gamepad's joysticks.

I have something like this but it never seems to get called or do anything. I am testing on a XOOM with JellyBean and my gamepad works for navigating around the menus.

```
@Override
public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    if ((e.getDevice().getSources() & InputDevice.SOURCE_CLASS_JOYSTICK) != 0) {
        float x = e.getX();
        float y = e.getY();
        mJoy1.set(x, y);
        mJoy2.set(-1,1);
        mRenderer.onAxisMoved(mJoy1, mJoy2);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

How do I go about reading the axis data from the gamepad?

Comment: Take a look at this: 
http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#motionevents

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516431/android-onscreen-joystick-issues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get it to work. I had to add these lines to the initialization of my view.

```
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

After that I was getting the function calls.