# Joystick API Android

Tags: android, api, joystick

The Android 3.1+ supports joystick and gamepad, but there are not any examples. I tried to use onTrackballEvent and it didn't work. How can I use joystick in my Android App?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123297/gamepad-support-android maybe it gives some insight on how to get it to work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516431/android-onscreen-joystick-issues